# Generate right mouse button click

Tags: mouse

ALL,

The standard Apple mouse has only one button that generates a left click. How do I generate a right click?

TIA!!

Comment: Which mouse is it? How old? What OS are you using? Apple mice since about 2005 have had 3-button capability, even if they appear to be a single flat surface.

Answer (score 1):

You can press the <kbd>control</kbd> key when clicking the mouse, or if you actually have an **Apple** mouse, check **Secondary click** in: **System Preferences** > **Mouse** > **Point & Click**

Note that other types of mouse may have a *right-click* setting in their preferences.